# How does adding another 9 to a phone number that can only start with either 8 or 9 make more phone numbers possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here in Brazil, Anatel (an institution that dictates how phone carriers should operate) has ordered that every phone numbers in the states of the Southeast (which is actually the southwest) must add an extra 9 to its already existing numbers in this fashion:

> 9xxxx-xxxx

But the problem with this (in my head) is that the second number (formerly the first) is always either 3, 8 or 9, the number that is being added before is always 9, and all the phones that could be taken are already taken (from third digit 1 to third digit 9). In the 70's, the limit of how many numbers a phone number could have were changed from 7 (xxxx-xxx) to 8 (xxxx-xxxx), meaning that new numbers could exist (3xxx-xxxx, 8xxx-xxxx and 9xxx-xxxx). How does adding a 9 to already existing and taken numbers increase how many numbers can be registered?

(I don't know which tags I should use, since this is such a simple question)

Comment: [More information here;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Brazil) It does seem like tilper's idea is right.

Comment: @Inazuma, now I see that I made a minor mistake. The formerly second numbers can go from 1 to 9, but I have only ever seen 3, 8 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal knowledge of the Brazilian telephone numbering system, but I can tell you what happened in Singapore, and maybe the same rationale applies.

Before $1995$, telephone numbers had just seven digits.

Pagers had become really big by then and mobile phones (cellular phones) were just starting to crack the market. So a '$9$' was added to pager and mobile phone numbers to distinguish them from landlines. This automatically allowed (with just that fixed prefix) $10^7$ theoretical possibilities for the mobile devices without any collision with fixed landlines.

In $2002$, landlines had a '$6$' prefixed to all of them. The rationale for this is less clear to me (for pretty much the same reasons you mentioned), but I can think of two non-mutually exclusive possibilities:

1) to immediately and clearly distinguish a fixed line from a mobile device.

2) to cater for projected expansion in numbers by allowing prefixes other than '$6$' (or '$9$') for new landline subscribers (anticipating increased immigration). This reason may be applicable to your question.

As it turned out in my country, I think they were being a little optimistic if their main driver was reason 2). Even though there was a big population increase, the number of landline subscribers has not really gone up proportionately. A lot of newcomers would rather just stick to mobile phones.

Further changes were made: An '$8$' prefix was added for newer mobile lines and '$3$' was added to cover new VoIP lines. So you see, adding prefixes does help to expand the number repertoire they can use, provided they're not sticking to just a single prefix digit.

Comment: What confuses me is that the wiki page linked by Inazuma states that Anatel stated that it makes more 46 million numbers possible. But I can't find any website that would explain *how* it makes more numbers possible when it's just adding a number to already taken phones.

Comment: @slashblock It wouldn't unless you allowed more varied prefix digits (i.e after the 9s ran out, start with the 8s and so forth). Like my real world example with my country's mobile phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new digit to the beginning, you now have a 9-digit number.  It sounded like all numbers before had fewer than 9 digits.  Therefore all 9-digit numbers should be not yet taken.

Comment: Think about it: If you added 9 to numbers of an already existing set (1-10), but _just_ 9, they would still essentialy be 10 numbers, since no number outside of 1-10 (now 9 1- 9 10) was made able to exist.

Comment: But if you *add an entirely new digit*, you can't possibly get a number you've already had, because none of the existing numbers would have this extra digit.  Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I'm interpreting that 9 as a addition that doesn't create a new unit (1 - 10, **1-10** 1 to **1-10** 10) that can exist, since it's fixed on 9.

Comment: I don't really understand what you meant by that, but when I look at your question, you said new numbers will have the form 9xxxx-xxxx.  That looks like nine total digits.  Is it correct that all new numbers will have nine total digits?

Comment: Nine total digits, but that extra digit will be only 9, and all other digits are already existent in the previous model

Comment: How many total digits can the existing numbers have?

Comment: **Before the change they could have eight numbers**: one which ranges from 2-10 (though I have only ever seen 3, 8 and 9) and other seven numbers that range from 1-10. **All of those were taken. Now they can have nine numbers.** The 9, one which ranges from 2-10 and other seven numbers that range from 1-10.

Comment: So, tell me, how can an 8-digit number possibly be identical to a 9-digit number if the 9-digit number begins with the number 9?  Can you give me an example of an 8-digit number and such a 9-digit number which are identical?

Comment: They are not *identical* mathematically, but practically the person ends up just adding one more number to an already existing phone number and completely obliterating the old phone number (the one without the 9), making up for the increase it would do.

Comment: I see, I think.  Based on Inazuma's link it looks like 8-digit numbers aren't going to be replaced.  Rather, the 9-digit numbers are a completely new addition.  If this is the case then there's no worry (yet) about running out of numbers.  When that becomes an issue they can likely just allow for different first digits.   If it *is* the case that 8-digit numbers will be replaced, then I think MathematicianByMistake's answer has the right idea.

Comment: The 8-digit numbers (on the states of the North and Midwest) won't be replaced now, but they will be replaced later.

Comment: In that case it's probably a mix.  Maybe for now they want to do what MBM was getting at, and the extra digit does allow for more possible numbers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the purpose is to add more numbers (that is to increase the number of combinations available for users to register) but rather to avoid misplaced calls.

That is, by adding another (pseudo)digit-I call it pseudo exactly because it does not alter the maximum amount of combinations-you create a "safe mechanism" for the system to correct any mistakes during the placement of the call. If the system "reads" one number wrong it might lead to another call-but reading two numbers (your two $9$s) is less probable, thus leading to far less misplaced calls.

This is more relevant to coding theory and error correction, and the way telecommunication systems work, it has nothing to do with the max of numbers available.

Comment: Though it has other reasons, they have explicitly stated that it also has the purpose to (free up) create more "available" numbers

Comment: "aumentar a disponibilidade de números na telefonia celular"

Comment: @slashblock Well, they likely plan to allow more digits to be available in the future. But regarding the problem in it's current form, I can't see how that is possible..The only reason that makes sense to me-and it is a common practice-is the one I stated..

Comment: Do you think it's possible that they have made a mistake? The wiki page linked by Inazuma states that it makes more 46 million numbers possible.

Comment: @slashblock I don't think they did make a mistake-these things are well planned. I am trying to see if I made one though :-)